# C# / WinForms: Highlight only the first item of a ListBox on drag & drop

Tags: c#, winforms

In a ListBox: User should be able to pick multiple items by holding the CTRL key and seleting them.  I have this working, but this ListBox needs to be able to do drag & drop of its items to another ListBox as well.  Now, when it comes to drag & drop, if the user holds down the left button of the mouse and continue scrolling down or up with it, it selects all other items that are moused over, but I do not want this. When the user holds down the left button to move the item by drag & drop I want him to just be able to pick that item and all other items should not be selected.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your ListBox's `SelectionMode` property is set to `MultiExtended`.  Setting this to `MultiSimple` should solve the problem.

Comment: True! But I switched it to MultiSimple and then with each single click on each item it was selecting it like I have held CTRL and clicking on the items

Comment: Can you post any custom code you've got related to this functionality?